# Remote form inside other remote form in Rails 3 disables nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, remote-forms

What I have is a `remote` form inside another `remote` form like this:

```
<%=form_for @myobj,:as=>:myobj,:url=>{:controller=>"my_controller",:action=>"first_action"},:remote=>true do |f|%>
   <%=form_for @myotherobj,:as=>:myotherobj,:url=>{:controller=>"my_controller",:action=>"second_action"},:remote=>true do |ff|%>
      <%=ff.submit "second"%>
   <%end%>
   <%=f.submit "first"%>
<%end%>
```

But then I click the second submit it doesn't do a remote call, It does a normal call with leads me to an error `Missing Template` because my action only responds to `JS` (Ajax Calls)

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but according to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org) you aren't allowed to nest [form tags](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/form.html#form-constraints).  That might be the overall issue with the forms itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested forms are invalid html.

The browsers behaviour is undefined what to do in such a case. It's just like trying to use IDs multiple times inside a html document. It will normally be the earliest occurrence of the ID that will be selected by a document.getElementById, and here you are finding the outermost (earliest) form is the one that is submitting.

If (at least) one of the forms is being submitted with javascript, then it would probably be better to create the form elsewhere and copy the values, or move the form elements prior to submitting.